# How to render Google meet invites in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I use Thunderbird as my main e-mail client and it works great, but google calendar invitations look terrible in it. Is there a plug-in, or settings I could use to make them look the same as in gmail web client? [example invitation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1hEj.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do the invitations look like in Thunderbird?